# Remove div tags in HTML in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, iframe

My aim is to store the binary format of HTML code in an iframe. I want to convert the tab into HTML. In JavaScript I converted the div content into HTML and through a hidden field I am getting the HTML content.

In that page I have an ajax HTML editor so I am getting big empty space. I am trying to remove it using regex like:

```
Regex.Replace(htmlformat,"divID",'')
```

But it's removing only the id like `div id=""style...` So it removes the space but it's not in the HTML format. So iframe webservice is not able to convert it into pdf.

I want to remove the div content with its tags in HTML using C#.

Comment: Please check this link:-https://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-html-tags

Comment: I want to remove entire div tags with its contents ..

Comment: I am trying to remove ajax html editor tags in html.Now i got the html tags by, var s =$("[id*=div_Notes]").html();Inside this div_notes i am trying to remove another div with its contents which contains ajax html editor tags.
var g =$("[id*=div_Text]").empty();$("[id*=hidden_field]").val(s);
But its doesn't work.How to remove html tags in this case.

Comment: What do you actually want please describe clearly & shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You will also want to allow for other things before class in the div tag

```
<div[^>]*class="footer"[^>]*>(.*?)</div>
```

Also, go case-insensitive. You may need to escape things like the quotes, or the slash in the closing tag. What context are you doing this in?

Also note that HTML parsing with regular expressions can be very nasty, depending on the input. A good point is brought up in an answer below - suppose you have a structure like:

```
<div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div>Hi!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Trying to build a regex for that is a recipe for disaster. Your best bet is to load the document into a DOM, and perform manipulations on that.

Pseudocode that should map closely to XML::DOM:

```
document = //load document
divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(div in divs) {
    if(div.getAttributes["class"] == "footer") {
        parent = div.getParent();
        for(child in div.getChildren()) {
            // filter attribute types?
            parent.insertBefore(div, child);
        }
        parent.removeChild(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside table i am containing many div and many tables too . Like <TABLE><BODY><TR>TD><DIV>...

Comment: I want to remove the particular div (which contains many div elements) and the div is in table element